# UWP, How to detect that a user have logged in before?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to develop an uwp application which needs to be logged once. How can i detect that the user have logged in before or not?

P.S. user may log out and it should show the log in page in next lunch.

Comment: All windows processes run under some logged in user... Please clarify what type of "log in" you are talking about.

Comment: It purely depends on what type of authentication you are using to log the user in. If it is simple and you do not care what type of credentials he is using @VijayNirmal's answer is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a value in `LocalSettings` after you LoggedIn for the first time

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LoggedIn"] = 1;
```

In App.xaml, Use the below code to check for the value

```
if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LoggedIn") == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you it helped